# UITextField Placeholder Text Replaced by Hold to Dictate message

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, tvos, apple-tv

I have a few standard UITextField's with placeholder text. Such as:

```
let emailTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: textFieldX, y: textFieldY, width: textFieldW, height: textFieldH))
emailTextField.tag = TV_SIGN_IN_TEXTVIEW_EMAIL
emailTextField.placeholder = "Email"
parentView.addSubview(emailTextField)
```

When I enter the screen it looks like:
[image: Initial]

I click on the textfield and see:
[image: Keyboard]

If I then press the Menu button without entering anything I get:
[image: Error]

As shown above the textfield's placeholder text now says "Hold [Microphone] to dictate" instead of "Email". I inspected the textfield object and checked the placeholder text and it still said it was set to "Email", so I can't fix it by just resetting the placeholder after leaving the keyboard. It almost seems to think it's still in focus. Focusing another button doesn't cause it to reset back to the placeholder, and in fact this can show up on multiple textfields at once. Is there any way to reset it back to showing my placeholder text?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting a keyboard type on the text field.

In your case:

emailTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress

Comment: That didn't bring back the placeholder,= when exiting the keyboard. It just uses the email style keyboard and changed it to say "Hold [mic] to spell" instead.

Comment: @ksiit Were you able to fix this problem?